# Mixing C++ and Fortran

Tags: c++, cmake, fortran, clang

**Is there a way to use the Clang compiler while mixing C++ and Fortran?**

Until now I use cmake with

```
project(mixing CXX Fortran)
```

but this triggers the use of `g++`.

> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0

CMakeLists.txt of my project with Fortran mixing:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.0)
project(mixing CXX Fortran)

# SET UP ROOT https://root.cern.ch/how/integrate-root-my-project-cmake
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} /opt/local/libexec/root6/etc/root/cmake)
find_package(ROOT REQUIRED COMPONENTS MATH MINUIT2)
include(${ROOT_USE_FILE})

include_directories(Experiment Theory ${ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(mixing main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mixing ${ROOT_LIBRARIES})
```

Not working, because g++ cannot use the needed Clang flag `-stdlib=libc++` of the ROOT library.

Comment: Can you show us how you are invoking cmake, specifically how you specified the toolchain?

Comment: @Frank I use the command `cmake ..` from my build folder. What do you mean by toolchain?

Comment: If you are using gfortran and g++ together (excluding clang++, a reasonable tactic) it would seem you should permit g++ to use -lstdc++.

Comment: There seems to be an example in the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25493039) which seems to show how to force different compilers.

Comment: @d_1999 I forced cmake now to use clang++ via `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++` and for now it seems to work fine.

Comment: @d_1999 are you planning to write a proper answer? There is a bounty, and it would be fair if you received it, as you pointed to the right direction. (Or, the owner of the answer in the linked question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always override c/c++ compiler by changing [CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html), where <LANG> in your case is C or CXX.

1. You can set your `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to override defaults for CMAKE_C_COMPILER  / CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

`CC=clang CXX=clang++ cmake`

2. You can set these on command line when invoking cmake:

`cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++`

3. You can also set these directly in your cmake file:

`set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)`

make sure however that you do that at the very top of your cmake file before any project/enable_language directive is used.

Comment: We found CMake is mostly broken for C++ projects. It will use the C compiler for tests even after setting the project to C++. We have experienced all kinds of stupid breaks, from failed feature tests to failed links because of it.

Comment: In the last 10 years I always didn't like cmake (even though I even pushed commits to cmake). Funny thing, right now our team is discussing switching to something else (cmake or ...) and I'm strongly against :)