# Using specific gfortran version/location using CMAKE

Tags: cmake, gfortran

I am using the "homebrew" package manager on macOS and I am trying to compile the AMBER package using CMAKE.

Is there a way to pass a location for gfortran on the command line? Using `/usr/local/bin/gfortran-7` specifically instead of `/usr/local/bin/gfortran`.

I am preferably looking for a solution which does not involve `alias` or `symlink`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this help? https://mixable.blog/how-to-set-c-c-or-fortran-compiler-for-cmake/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiling with clang and gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493039/compiling-with-clang-and-gfortran).  That is, set the variable `CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER` to the path of the compiler you want to use.

Comment: @vre It just might, it does seem like what I am looking for. I just have to find the rest of the environment variables I would need in the next step to "downgrade" openmpi to one that is supported by the "older" gcc version. Looking at the comment by francescalus below, is would Fortran and FC be interchangeable?

Comment: @francescalus This seems, according to the answer provided by vre, like something I would have to edit in a file. This is something I'd prefer to avoid if possible though I will try to check both suggestion and see if I can get a working solution. Thanks to both

Comment: @gusgrave, you should be able to supply that variable on the command line like any other: `cmake ... -DCMAKE_fortran_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/gfortran-7`.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you, did not find this syntax in the manual. Using homebrew with the strange apple system with the to me new cmake has proven to be challenging. Setting the environmental variables changed nothing. Even when specifying the gnu compilers and adding aliases it finds "clang". I'll keep trying and go digging through the cmake files to find where and what to modify.

Comment: @francescalus So it seems that this should work though in an effort to "simplify" the install some options have been set and are ignored. `Manually-specified variables were not used by the project: CMAKE_fortran_COMPILER`. I suppose I'll have to figure out how cmake works and go looking through the configuration files.

Comment: So obviously, the suggestions here solves the problem in general. It just does not work very well for me with the software I am trying to compile and my lacking knowledge regarding cmake. Thank you to both

Comment: It should read `CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER`, note the uppercase `F`.